# What is dag in python? How is it used?

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs

I am new to python, so bear with me. I see functions in python like below:

@dag.cellfn(dag.CanSet)

def XYZ(self):

```
  return None
```

whats the purpose of such functions?

Answer (score 0):

@ denotes a decorator function. What this means is that before your XYZ function gets called, it will first call the dag.cellfn function with 2 arguments, a reference to XYZ and dag.CanSet. The decorated function (dag.cellfn) will do whatever it was written to do and eventually call the reference function (XYZ).

Decorators are often used to minimize code repetition, say you want to wrap every one of your functions with a try/catch. The decorator will let you write the try/catch once and then execute any function inside it.

You should read the python documentation for decorators.